# Simplifying nested pure functions

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions

I have several functions:

```
A=Function[{u},Piecewise[{{1/Sqrt[2],u==0},{1,u!=0}}]]
Cc=Function[{i,u},A[u]*Cos[((2*i+1)*u*Pi)/16]]
IDCT1=Function[{i,j},1/4*Sum[Sum[Cc[i,u]*Cc[j,v]*Q[u,v]*Y1[u,v], {v,0, 7}],{u, 0, 7}]]
IDCT2=Function[{i,j},1/4*Sum[Sum[Cc[i,u]*Cc[j,v]*Q[u,v]*Y2[u,v], {v,0, 7}],{u, 0, 7}]]
```

where `Q` is a matrix

`FullSimplify` accepts expressions, not functions.

How do I simplify `ICDT1[i,j]*ICDT2[i,j]` without rewriting everything as expressions?

Comment: `FullSimplify[ICDT1[i, j] * ICDT2[i, j]]` will already (try to) simplify the resulting expression. Would that not work?

Answer (score 2):

```
IDCT = Function[{i, j}, Evaluate@FullSimplify[IDCT1[i, j]*IDCT2[i, j]]]
```

(takes a while to evaluate)

Comment: Cannot check because it times out....

Comment: Try replacing `FullSimplify` with `Simplify`, `Factor`, or whatever you need. My point was only to show you how to stay with functions instead of expressions, not how to simplify your specific terms.